# What is the most elegant way to view a multipage PDF in iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I am stuck in a predicament whereby I hope someone can help me.

I am consuming a web service that returns a multi page PDF document as a Base64 payload. I want to be able to view the PDF on a page by page basis. For example I get the following  string back in a long Base 64 encoded form within image tags :

> ```
> <image>JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL01vZER........</image>
> ```

I am not wanting to use a UIWebView to view the fax but a simple very basic PDF viewer with pagination. I know there are some libraries like Fast PDF Kit but that would not work because they show the logo and the license is a little pricey.

I am a PDF newbie so if someone can show by a small example I would truly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use UIWebView since it probably does everything you need. PDF parsing guide from Apple will show you how to implement this by hand:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html